# $a$ transcendental $\implies a^a$ is transcendental?

Tags: field-theory, transcendental-numbers

> Suppose $a\in \mathbb{C}$ is not a algebraic number. Then is $a^{a}$ also
>   transcendental number ?

I've not idea about how to do it. I got motivation for asking this question from the fact that $e^{i\pi}$ is rational while $e,i\pi$ both are transcendental.

Comment: The solution to $x^x=2$ is perhaps not algebraic?

Comment: @Aravind It is assuredly transcendental: if $x$ were algebraic then Gelfond-Schneider implies $2$ is transcendental... which it isn't :).

Comment: @Spenser Good point, it isn't immediate that $x$ is irrational, but it should follow easily from FTA.

Comment: @ErickWong It does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let us take $x=\exp\left(W(\log 2)\right)$, i.e. a solution of $x^x=2$.

**Step 1.** $x\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.
Assuming $x=\frac{p}{q}$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$, we have $p^p=2^q\cdot q^p$, absurd.

**Step 2.** $x$ is not an algebraic number.
Assuming that $x$ is in algebraic number, the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) gives that $2$ is a transcendental number. It is not, so:

> $\color{red}{\text{your claim does not hold.}}$

Answer (score 1):

$$ x^x=2$$ if $x=a/b$ then $$x^a=2^b $$ therefore $x$ is irrational. According to Gelfond Scheninder theorem $$a^b$$ is transcendental for $a b$ algebraic, $a\neq0,1,\,b$ irrational . $$x^x= 2\implies x \text{ transcendental.}$$